# Clarification needed about behaviour of java volatile keyword

Tags: java, multithreading, volatile

I have been reading about the 'volatile' keyword because our application is full of variables of this type. This was done a lot of years ago, and now reviewing it I want to confirm some points. As an example:

```
private volatile int responseTimeout;
```

This variable is responsible to store the maximum wait time our application will wait for a response to be received from the backend servers. It's read every time we need to send a request to the backend, but it's barely modified (maybe once a year).

Our application is an api gateway that has thousands of reader threads BUT just one writer, that occassionaly writes some of these volatile variables.

From my understanding:

- if responseTimeout is volatile with a value of 3000 and thread B changes it to 5000, after this write all reader threads will immediately see the new value of 5000.
- if responseTimeout is not volatile with a value of 3000 and thread B changes it to 5000, after this write some reader threads will immediately see the new value of 5000 and some others will still see the old value of 3000 for a short period of time (until the change is propagate to all cpu registers).

If this is right, for us it is fine that after a write some threads still see the old value for a short period of time. That's why we plan to remove this 'volatile' keyword.

So here the question. What will not happen is that some reader threads will see a different value of 3000 or 5000 because they are trying to read something that is not completely written yet by the thread B. Is this true?

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the volatile keyword useful for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106591/what-is-the-volatile-keyword-useful-for)

Comment: The linked page explains that your assumptions are wrong: if you have one writer and multiple readers you need `volatile`, if you have multiple writers you need `synchronized`.

Answer (score 3):

We can't give a reliable *a priori* prediction about how long it will take for a thread to see the updated value (if you remove the `volatile`).  Indeed, it is possible that a given thread will **never** see the updated value.  In practice, it will depend on a number of factors including such things as Java / JIT compiler versions, the hardware ISA, the number of cores that are used, how heavily loaded the system is, and various aspects of how the application requests work.

The flipside to your question is: What do you hope to gain by doing this?  Is your system so loaded that the cost of one extra `volatile` read per request is going to be significant?  Have you *measured* the performance impact?

Also, consider alternatives.  For example, if you only change this once a year, couldn't you hold the setting in a `final` variable and **restart** your application whenever you need to change the setting?

Comment: I have hundreds of volatile variables, I don't know if I'm going to gain anything, I should test ... but if you say that there is even a chance for a thread to not see the updated value I'm not going to remove volatile. This app is managing more than 40.000 req/s and must be live 24x365, so a restart is not a choice. Thanks!

Comment: A single instance system that needs to be 24 x 365 is a mistake.  A single point of failure.  You need an architecture that allows multiple instances with fail-over.  And that means that restarting is not a scary thing.  Sounds like you are trying to solve the wrong problem(s) first ...

Comment: Yes, you are right. I will send your comments to our client, it's the same thing we have repeated them for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

If the variable is mostly readonly, it is relatively cheap. The cache line containing the volatile variable, will probably be in 'SHARED' state (see the MESI cache coherence algorithm for more details) on multiple CPUs concurrently. So each CPU can just read that cache line from its local cache without the need for expensive cache coherence messages or communication with main memory.

There is a price to pay for a volatile read, in the form of compiler restrictions and potentially some CPU memory ordering fences in case of e.g ARM. But on the X86 even memory fences are not needed because every load is an acquire load which is [sufficient](https://shipilev.net/blog/2014/on-the-fence-with-dependencies/).

In short: in most applications, a volatile read isn't something to worry about from a performance perspective.